# I need to merge User Profiles

Tags: support, magento, profile-page, user-accounts

From your side told, we removed your one of your other profiles with any notification. How can I merged my this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/268415/rathinam  into this https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39050/rathinam.

Actually, so many questions are there. I need my both account should be merged. Help me regard this issue ASAP.

Current Profile : https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39050/rathinam

blocked profile: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/57161/rathinam & https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/268415/rathinam & https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/57161/rathinam

I need my account details back. Valuable knowledge is there. Help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you accidently deleted your account?

Answer (score 1):

One account was blocked because of abusing the voting system. (I know this, b/c I put this under investigation)

Why should anybody help now?